# Here route API - Calculating toll cost

Tags: here-api

I am trying to calculate the toll cost between two points in Australia.

Here is the sample URL i am using at the moment:

http://tce.cit.api.here.com/1/tollcost.json?region=AUS&release=2015Q1&start_ts=now&vspec=3%3B0%3B0%3B2%3B0%3B0%3B5%3B340%3B0%3B7500%3B7500%3B0%3B0%3B0%3B1%3B4%3B1%3B0&route=1353326419097748185%3B1353396779235213606&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg

The response i get back is:

```
{
    "errors": [
        "Error id: fc4bc014-a17a-4efb-a346-4fad9d01a0ef",
        "A technical error occurred while processing the toll cost. Please contact TCS."
    ],
    "warnings": [
        "The combination \"link id,remaining time\" for element number \"1\" is invalid. The automatic datetime filtering will be disabled."
    ],
    "countries": [],
    "onError": true
}
```

Not sure if the issue is my linkId's, region, map release, or something entirely different.

I'm not finding a lot of useful documentation or feedback for this, so some help would be much appreciated :)

edit:

We ended up building our own solution, though it only supports QLD & NSW so far. Might have to licence it out some day ;)

Comment: API doc: https://developer.here.com/documentation/download/routing_road_pricing_nlp/1.1.0/Toll%20Cost%20Extension%20API%20v1.1.0%20Developer's%20Guide.pdf. Not sure how much help.

Comment: Just what I was looking for :D

Comment: Even when i use the sample url's from the documentation i get the same error. I was thinking it might have something to do with the linkId's not matching the map release, but in that case the samples would still work..

Comment: Seems like its got something to do with the versions you are using. This might help:  https://developer.here.com/documentation/versions

You download the latest version and try implementing the same. The API params might have changed over the course. https://developer.here.com/documentation/download/traffic_nlp/6.0.42.0/Traffic%20API%20v6.0.42.0%20Developer's%20Guide.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation example have the version which are not supported now, HERE will update its documentation and regrets the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the map toll API for Australia and had issues too. I created a support ticket and the response was that Australia toll calculations are not covered yet.

[image]

Comment: Do you know any other api which we can use to implement the same? It'll be great help as I am stuck with not finding one.

Answer (score 0):

The link ID 1353326419097748185 is not a valid link ID.
Please use the link IDs provided in the response of the HERE router.

You don't have to work with link IDs, you can also provide the start/destination coordinates, so that the toll cost service computes the route.

Examples: https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/route_toll_cost
Search for TCE, the 3rd example computes the route and adds the toll cost.